# Determine Yii accessRules from another controller, before the action is called

Tags: php, yii, authorization

Is there a sensible way to determine whether the current user can access an action on a different controller, based on the accessRules for that controller and the accessControl filter?

For example, I don't want to display a link that goes to a controller action that the user doesn't have permission to access, based on their role and the rules defined in that controller's accessRules().

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566571/yii-i-want-to-get-all-actions-that-a-user-is-authorized-to-perform
The answer given says it isn't possible. Anybody know any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is no different due to how Yii handles it's controllers.

The only way would be to parse the controller yourself and add its own rules as part of your controller dynamically in your code and then evaluate whether or not the user is allowed to access a particular function through bizrule call.

But the answer in the linked question in the comment is a sensible one and is preferred for more complex role based access management. Since the rules are externally stored you can just call the check function with the controller and its action and bam, you have your true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely:

```
    Yii::import('application.controllers.YourControllerName');
    $controller = new YourControllerName($this->id);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($controller->accessRules());
    echo '</pre>';
```

You can access to rules of a specific controllers. Also, you can determine if current user can see or not a specific action of a specific controller =).

Comment: Thanks, obviously it's possible to get access to the accessRules, but I want to do the same parsing and filtering of them that the accessFilter does (i.e. CAccessControlFilter) but that relies on it being a normal request.